# Vaadin MySQL fetch

Tags: java, mysql, vaadin

I can't understand how to fetch a database result set using Vaadin.
First I do:

```
JDBCConnectionPool pool=null;
try{
    pool = new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool(dbClass, dbUrl, "root", "toor");
}catch(SQLException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FreeformQuery query = new FreeformQuery(query_s, pool, "id");
try {
    SQLContainer container = new SQLContainer(query);
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and now what should I do? (`query_s` is a simple query string like SELECT * FROM users)
I'm trying to use Freeformstatementdelegate but I don't know how to use it. Is it the best choice for a code like above?

Comment: `...and now what should I do?` What do you want to do? Do you want to display results somehow? Do you get some errors?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to read-only result from database, you don't need to use `FreeformStatementDelegate`.

You can just set datas to table by:

```
  Table table = new Table();
  table.setContainerDataSource(sqlContainer);
```

or set result to list:

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (Object ob : this.sqlContainer.getItemIds())
  {
      list.add(sqlContainer.getItem(ob).getItemProperty(columnName).getValue());
  }
```

But if you want also filtering, sorting, removing and lazy loading features, you must use `FreeformStatementDelegate`.

1) Create custom class; 
 2) Implement `FreeformStatementDelegate` interface and override methods;
 3) set `FreeformQuery.setDelegate(new CustomClass);`